# Using a SQL correlated sub-query with exists operator

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, where-clause

I'm trying to find all records in the job_history table with their department_ID is not the same as department_id in employees table by using a correlated sub-query with exists operator, however, I'm getting the error code:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Can someone tell please tell me what I'm doing wrong based on the schema and code below?

```
Select * 
from Job_History as J 
where Exists(Select * from hr.Employees e where e.Department_ID != J.Department_ID);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
from Job_History as J
```

Oracle does not support keyword `as` to alias a table (it is supported in column aliases only).

You also most probably want a correlation clause on the `employee_id` in the subquery.

So:

```
select * 
from job_history j 
where exists (
    select 1 
    from hr.employees e 
    where e.employee_id = j.employee_id and e.department_id <> j.department_id
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I was able to get an answer by adding hr to job_history below. Sorry for not mentioning I was using Oracle SQL live hence the reason I had to add HR when selecting the table. See below:                                                     
select * 
from hr.job_history j 
where exists (
    select 1
    from hr.employees e 
    where e.employee_id = j.employee_id 
    and e.department_id <> j.department_id);